# In IIS URL Rewrite 2.0, why does HTTP_HOST include the port number?

Tags: url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to use [IIS URL Rewrite 2.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) with IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1.  According to [Accessing URL Parts from a Rewrite Rule](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule),

```
For an HTTP URL in this form: http(s)://<host>:<port>/<path>?<querystring>

• The <path> is matched against the pattern of the rule.
• The <querystring> is available in the server variable called QUERY_STRING and can be accessed by using a condition within a rule.
• The <host> is available in the server variable HTTP_HOST and can be accessed by using a condition within a rule.
• The <port> is available in the server variable SERVER_PORT and can be accessed by using a condition within a rule.
• Server variables SERVER_PORT_SECURE and HTTPS can be used to determine if a secure connection was used. These server variables can be accessed by using a condition within a rule.
• The server variable REQUEST_URI can be used to access the entire requested URL path, including the query string.
```

To test that, here is the rule I used:

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/?{HTTP_HOST}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

Then I used the Composer tab in Fiddler to create the following request:

```
http://localhost.localdomain:65352/
```

to which IIS responded

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://localhost/?localhost.localdomain:65352
```

From this we can see that the port number is included in the HTTP_HOST variable, contrary to the documentation referenced above. This adds some complexity to my matching rules because I must then account for the optional presence of a port number. How do I just get the hostname without the port number?

Comment: FYI: I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9713).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't tell you why it happens; but I can tell you that using `{SERVER_NAME}` instead of `{HTTP_HOST}` fixed the issue for me.

See: https://serverfault.com/a/418530/3495